# Create a dropdown from a list of links using JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a td that contains some links.

I want to convert these links into dropdown options (the links load a new page or carryout further changes on the page)

```html
<td class="listActions">
    <a href="/edit">edit</a>
    <a href="/eraseRecordOnThisPage">erase</a>
    <a href="/payments">Payment</a>
    <a href="/cancel">Cancel</a>
</td>
```

I would like to create a dropdown inside the td.

Any ideas how I would go about doing that using Javascript or JQuery(<2.0)

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far. To begin with, use the `td` class to get all the link texts in an array and then create a dropdown html and populate using the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all `a` tags in the `td`, and create html string for corresponding `option` elements. Then you can wrap these options in `select` tag and append to the `td` in question.

```
<td class="listActions">
    <a href="/edit">edit</a>
    <a href="/eraseRecordOnThisPage">erase</a>
    <a href="/payments">Payment</a>
    <a href="/cancel">Cancel</a>
</td>

<script>
    $(".listActions").each(function(index){
        var htmlString = '<select>';

        $(this).find("a").each(function(){
            htmlString += '<option value="'+$(this).attr("href")+'">'+$(this).text()+'</option>';
        });//each

        htmlString += '</select>';

        $(this).append( htmlString );
    });//each

  $('.listActions').on('change', function() {
    window.location = $(this).val();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using JQuery (but this opens the selected link)

```js
$('#selectURL').on('change', function() {
  window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="listActions">
  <select id="selectURL">
    <option value="" selected="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="/eraseRecordOnThisPage">eraseRecordOnThisPage</option>
    <option value="/payments">payments</option>
    <option value="/cancel">cancel</option>
  </select>


</td>
```